# Excluding posts from search results page with meta query not working

Tags: wp-query, search, advanced-custom-fields, pre-get-posts

On my search results page I have two loops. First loop displays post by meta value and second loop is "regular" loop that display posts by search query:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-5">
                
            <?php // a "static" custom loop displaying posts by meta value  
            $featured_posts = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => array( 'cpt-1', 'cpt-2', 'cpt-3' ),
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'   => 'highlight', // this is a name of ACF field
                        'value' => '1',
                    )
                )
            ) );
            
            echo '<div class="col-12">';
            
            if ( $featured_posts ) {
                    echo '<h3>Highlighted posts (' . $featured_posts->found_posts . '):</h3>';

                    while ( $featured_posts->have_posts() ) : $featured_posts->the_post();
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' );
                    endwhile;
                
                    wp_reset_postdata();
            } else {
                echo 'No any highlighted post.';
            }
            
            echo '</div>';
            ?>
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                
                <?php 
                global $wp_query;
                //$allsearch = new WP_Query( 's=' . $s . '&showposts=0' ); ?>
                
                <h3>The search results (<?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; //echo $allsearch->found_posts; ?>):</h3>
                
                <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) : 
                    //echo '<table>';

                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' );
                    endwhile;
                    //echo '</table>'; ?>
    
                    <div class="pagination-area">
                        <nav class="navigation pagination" role="navigation">
                            <div class="nav-links">

                                <?php
                                global $wp_query;

                                $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

                                echo paginate_links( array(
                                    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                                    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                                    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
                                    'prev_text'    => __( '«' ),
                                    'next_text'    => __( '»' ),
                                ) );
                                ?>
                                
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>

                <?php
                else :

                    echo 'No search results.';

                endif; ?>
                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The highlighted posts are displaying in both loops. Now I want to exclude them from regular search results loop with `pre_get_posts` :

```
function my_custom_search_query( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() || $query->is_search() ) {
        $query->set('meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'highlight',
                'value' => '0'
            )
        ) );        
    }


}
add_action('pre_get_posts','my_custom_search_query');
```

This code does not work properly, because:

1. it removes posts from both loops on search results page, not from only "regular" loop
2. it removes more than highlighted posts...

I also tried to use here `$query->is_main_query()` with no success.

Comment: note that searching via `meta_query` is very expensive, you should use a custom taxonomy or highlight tag/category to back that field rather than post meta as filtering/searching by term is ultra fast in comparison. Exclusions/NOT IN queries are even more expensive. These types of queries get dramatically slower as the number of posts and post meta increases

Comment: That second loop uses the main query, so no matter what, your `if` needs to check `$query->is_main_query()`. So `if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() )` should work. And your meta query needs two clauses *with an OR relation* - first clause: checks if the value is `0`, and the other clause is one that has `'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'`. But I agreed with Tom - you could have just assigned the "highlighted" posts in a category (or custom taxonomy *term*) named `Highlighted` or something better.. And then your query would become easier.

Comment: Hello @SallyCJ, i'm using "highlight" field at three custom post types. My search page displays results from all of them by various parameters as taxonomies. Your if statement works good and excludes all "highlighted" post from results, but now, it displays results from only one of three custom post types...

Comment: @TomJNowell, thank You and what means "very expensive" in my case? ACF documentation says, I should to use meta_query array parameter https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/ :)

Comment: to query post meta yes, but finding post by their meta is expensive, it has a high resource cost on the database server, the query can takes longer to run and is slower, and it means fewer of these queries can run at the same time reducing the number of people who can view your site at the same time. It's a performance issue, expensive things are slow, cheap things are _fast_. It's not how you query post meta, it's that you're doing it at all, this is why categories tags and other taxonomies aren't stored in post meta but are stored in dedicated tables that make this type of query fast.

Comment: So ACF is right that you should use `meta_query` to find posts with a particular piece of post meta (or fields as ACF calls them), but finding posts by their meta value is _slooow_ and gets exponentially slower as your site grows. This gives the illusion that it's fast when your site is small, or has no visitors.